# I cannot write to my .json file hosted on Cyclic because of "errno: -30 code: EROFS"

Tags: node.js-fs, cyclic

This error occurs when I write to the .json file this is deployed on Cyclic via GitHub. I can only read data from the file but cannot write to it. Please help.[my code to write to file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjwNe.png)
[payload received when writing to the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOwYH.png)[my express and route code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaxBs.png)

I tried changing the directory name from ./collection to /temp as suggested by many on a similler post but to no avail.